# Room diacritic insensitive query

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-room

I'm working on Room databse in my app and I've encountered a problem. Names of products in my databse contain Polish letters like "ąćęłóżź". I have a searchbox that searches for a product by name. This is my query:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM Suggestion WHERE name LIKE :name")
fun getSuggestionByName(name: String): Single<List<Suggestion>>
```

I want my query to ignore diacritic signs, so that when the user types "mroz" he would get all combination results such as:

- "mroz"
- "mróz"
- "mroż"
- "mróż"

For now it only returns matches that contain what the user entered (mroz).

I tried

```
  @Query("SELECT * FROM Suggestion WHERE name COLLATE NOCASE LIKE :name")
```

and COLLATE LOCALIZED but that didn't work.